# Auto Save Picklist value onchange

Tags: event, actionfunction, actionsupport, action, outputfield

I have an apex page where there is only one picklist field whose value change is allowed by User. Now I don't need a Save button to make the change reflect in system. Instead I need that anytime User change the picklist value it gets saved automatically. I have below code snippet which is not working as desired. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

Please find the solution I was able to place here. Thanks!

```
              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                         action="{!savei}"/>

            </apex:inputField> 
            </apex:actionRegion>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create such picklists using the resources I linked out too. You would simply query the table and then populate a List of type SelectOption. The problem here would be using such a picklist in a standard page since it would be embedded in the layout within it's own iFrame, and therefore be inaccessible to the standard controller.

Your other options are:

1. Create a completely custom visualforce page
2. Create a trigger on the "Picklist values object/table" that makes a web service call to an intermediate system that makes a web service call back into SFDC using the metadata api and updates the metadata for a picklist on the object of your choice depending on what's added to/changed/removed from the table.

I hope this might be useful for you if i wrong then please correct me.